# Python pdfminer pdf2html: apostrophes converted to special characters

Tags: python, encoding, pdfminer

I'm using the pdfminer package in Python to convert a PDF to HTML, but it converts apostrophes to special characters. Example:

`â€˜This is a text between apostrophesâ€™`

Should be:

`'This is a text between apostrophes'`

Is there any way to convert the special characters back to apostrophes or to change the encoding or something? I'm not really familiar with character encodings. Maybe I can pick an encoding for the conversion to HTML?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to read the PDF? And can you specify the Python version that you're using (the API to ``pdfminer`` has changed between 2.x and 3.x)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the quotes are the unicode characters 'LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2018) and 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019). Encoded in utf-8 they are:

```
'\xe2\x80\x98This is a text between apostrophes\xe2\x80\x99'
```

The bytes in this text are:

```
'\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xcb\x9cThis is a text between apostrophes\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xe2\x84\xa2'
```

This is 8 bytes per quote, which makes me wonder if the string was encoded multiple times. I tried several combinations like:

```
>>> u'\u2018'.encode('utf-8').decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa2\xc2\x80\xc2\x98'
```

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the result you got.